# Обработка ajax запросов

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Всем добрый день. Я перешел к изучению ajax технологии и на просторах интернета, практически на всех сайтах, используется один и тот-же пример в разных вариациях. Ознакомившись со всеми этими сайтами, перелопатив одну и ту-же информацию, я решил узнать у реальных людей как мне изучить этот вопрос.

1. Существует ли интернет ресурс, где можно подробно и с примерами изучить тему?
2. Можно ли обрабатывать множество запросов в одном файле ajax.php?
   2.1 Если можно, то напишите простенький пример или киньте ссылку пж))))
   2.1 Можно или нет подключить в этот обработчик RedBeanPHP? Или придется писать запросы на чистом SQL
3. Если вдруг приспичит, то можно ли обработать ajax запрос в index.php среди прочего кода???

Если будете писать пример, то напишите пж с JQuery а не с чистым Js.

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: ajax запрос практически не отличается от любого другого запроса из браузера. Соответственно вы можете делать в его обработчике все то, что делаете в обычных страницах, включая работу с БД с помощью любых библиотек. И конечно обрабатывать самые разные запросы одним файлом. буквально расставив if/switch/более сложные методы выбора, которые вызовут в зависимости от запроса разные функции

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите работать с бэкендом, то рекомендую сразу идти в сторону [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) для веб-приложений и/или [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/)/[Slim 4](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/) для постройки [RESTful API](https://searchapparchitecture.techtarget.com/definition/RESTful-API#:%7E:text=A%20RESTful%20API%20is%20an,to%20communicate%20with%20each%20other.).

Допустим, Вы написали/создали API для работы с блогом на Lumen/Slim 4/Laravel и Вам нужно получить данные с серверной части. Как же оформить jQuery запросы?
Всё очень просто. Вот сразу пример в лоб:

`api.js`

```js
window._api = {
  blog: {
    _data: {
      articles: [],
      article: null
    }
  }
};
```

`api/blog.js`

```js
// -- Setters
window._api.blog.setArticle = article => {
  window._api.blog._data.article = article;
};

window._api.blog.setArticles = articles => {
  window._api.blog._data.articles = articles;
};


// -- Blog / Articles
window._api.blog.getArticle = id => {
  $.get(
    `/api/v1/blog/articles/${id}`,
    response => {
      window._api.blog.setArticle(response.data.article);
    }
  )
};

window._api.blog.getArticles = () => {
  $.get(
    `/api/v1/blog/articles`,
    response => {
      window._api.blog.setArticles(response.data);
    }
  )
}
```

Также, отвечу на Ваши вопросы:

1. Да, есть ресурсы
   1.1 [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)
   1.2 [JSON API](https://jsonapi.org/)
2. Нет, нельзя. Для этого существуют MVC паттерны в которых четко и ясно прописана логика обработки данных/событий. Controller отвечает только за получение данных и отправку результата, Service Layer - за обработку данных, Repository - за работу с базой данных/таблицей и их сущностями/записями.
   Как пример для API - моё [тестовое задание](https://github.com/KielD-01/quantox-test-task), которое я писал.
   Запросы писать лучше с помощью/использованием ORM. Упростит Вам жизнь и уровень безопасности будет немного выше, чем Вы бы писали сами.
   А по поводу обработчиков - советую покопать в сторону [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) и [Cassandra DB](https://cassandra.apache.org/).
3. Нет, нельзя. `index.php` - это входная точка, с которой пользователь уже будет перенаправлен на основную логику Вашего приложения.
   Это такой себе Front Controller на который ссылается nGinx либо apache настройки (mod_rewrite [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)/[apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html))

Надеюсь, что мой ответ поможет Вам разобраться.
Удачи Вам в начинаниях.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ, но я не так сильно погрузился чтобы работать с API  и ни разу не пробовал и если честно не особо знаю что как и зачем это нужно   :( если Вы читаете этот комментарий, то ответьте пожалуйста ещё на 1 вопрос, а точнее на неразбериху с ответами. Одни люди говорят, что можно обрабатывать все запросы в одном файле через switch, if  и другими способами, а Вы ответили, что это невозможно. +1 подвопрос как к специалисту. Я самостоятельно, криво, но пытаюсь написать web сайт без фреймворков. Ошибка ли писать в index.php или в прочие страницы php код? Или его лучше подгружать?

Answer (score -1):

1. Официальный сайт jQuery
2. Да.
3. Да.

Comment: Ответ дан слишком коротко. Информации недостаточно для человека, задающего вопрос. К тому же, отсутствует пример, который был упомянут.